# In django, how can I have two different methods for instantiating the same model?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin, django-polymorphic

I am building a system to register parts for manufacturing (for context: temperature sensors).

As I'm dealing with many different subtypes of actual physical parts, I'm using django-polymorphic to define the models for the actual temperature sensors:

```
class TempSensor(PolymorphicModel):
    """Abstract model for temperature sensors""""
    part_number = models.OneToOneField(Part, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

```
class TempSensorA1(TempSensor):
    calibration = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=Calibration.choices)
    junction = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=Junction.choices)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"A1-{self.calibration}{self.junction}"
```

```
class TempSensorB1(TempSensor):
    calibration = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=Calibration.choices)
    termination = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=Termination.choices)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"B1-{self.calibration}{self.termination}"
```

The `Part` model acts as a container for the `TempSensor` instances. This lets me assign a simpler consecutive part number and associate them with orders.

```
class Part(models.Model):
    part_number = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

    order = models.ManyToManyField(Order, through="OrderDetail")

    production_notes = models.TextField(blank=True)
    sales_notes = models.TextField(blank=True)
        
    class Meta:
        ordering = ["part_number"]
```

---

Right now, I have the django admin interface working as expected. When adding a new `Part` instance, I can add a `TempSensor`, select the correct child type and input the fields manually, all through an inline. This works great when working from raw specifications.

However, since model codes are often provided directly, I also need to be able to instantiate `TempSensor` directly from the model code.

---

To solve this, I've created a `create_from_model_code` method that takes the model code, parses it to identify the correct `TempSensor` subtype, and instantiates the model accordingly. This works well, but I can't figure out how to integrate both methods into admin simultaneously.

Ideally, I would have "Create temperature sensor" and "Create from model code" buttons that would load the correct form. Alternatively, I've thought of using `create_from_model_code` to get the desired values and fill out the form, but I'm not sure how to do that.

**What is the best way to have two different methods of instantiating a model?**

Answer (score -2):

You can use [generic relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations) to solve your problem

Comment: I'm not sure how generic relationships solve my issue... PolymorphicModel handles the relationships between models correctly. What I'm looking for is how I can add second way to instantiate an existing model. Could you elaborate?